# Push Notification Problema con Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, app, push-notification

Estoy Utilizando el servicio de notifications de Firebase para recibir push notifications en mi APP, el problema radica cuando la Aplicacion esta en segundo plano o muerta, si me llegan las notificaciones pero no se ven como yo las construyo(Le asigno un small icon, large icon, sonido y vibracion), ya estuve checando en la documentacion de firebase  vienen unos meta que se tienen que agregar en el Manifest (los anexo mas abajo) para armar la notificación por si no tiene datos, el problema es que solo se establece el fondo y el icono, quisiera saber si existe un metodo que cree la notificación con ciertos parametros para yo poder establecer los mios cuando la app este en segundo plano o muerta.

meta-data en el MANIFEST

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icono" />

 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

ARCHIVO JAVA PARA EL TOKEN

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

public static final String TAG = "LePanier";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG,"Token: " + token);
}
}
```

ARCHIVO JAVA QUE RECIBE EL MENSAJE

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static final String TAG = "PRUEBA";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String From = remoteMessage.getFrom();      //De donde viene el mensaje

    Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje Recibido de: " + From);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!= null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Notificación: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        String Titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String Mensaje = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        MostrarNotificacion(Titulo,Mensaje);

    }

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Data: " +  remoteMessage.getData());

        String Titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String Mensaje = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        MostrarNotificacion(Titulo,Mensaje);

    }

}
```

FUNCION PARA CREAR MI NOTIFICACION

```
private void MostrarNotificacion(String Titutlo, String Mensaje)



{

    Uri sonido = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.lepanier.lepanier/" + R.raw.timbrebicicleta);

    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};


    Resources resources = getResources();
    int color1 = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);


    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icono_large);




    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaginaInicio.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pushnotifications);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(Titutlo);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(Mensaje);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(sonido);
            notificationBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setColor(color1);
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());




}
```

}

Comment: Hola Jesus,
Las notificaciones por defecto que vienen implementadas con Firebase todavía tienen algunos problemas. las notificaciones van a salir siempre de la consola de Firebase o las vas a enviar desde un servidor propio?

Comment: Hola, ya me resigne, las notificaciones saldran siempre de firebase, he estado checando algunas Aplicaciones que ya tengo instaladas y a excepcion de facebook y whatsapp. las demas tienen el mismo problema que yo, cuando la App esta en sgeundo plano o cerrada la notificacion se muestra de distinta forma a cuando la App esta abierta